# Rails 3 and carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I use Rails 3 and Carrierwave. I have two models: `Gallery` and `GalleryPicture`:

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gallery_pictures
end

class GalleryPicture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gallery
  mount_uploader :gallery_pic, GalleryUploader
end
```

How I can save a picture and a gallery? The following doesn't save the picture:

```
gallery = params[:gallery].delete(:gallery_pic)
@gallery = Gallery.new(params[:gallery])
@gallery.gallery_pictures << GalleryPicture.new(gallery)
@gallery.save
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find this helpful
http://blog.assimov.net/post/4306595758/multi-file-upload-with-uploadify-and-carrierwave-on

you can use following in your model

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base


 has_many   :gallery_pictures,  :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :gallery_pictures

end

class GalleryPicture < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :gallery
  mount_uploader :gallery_pic, GalleryPicUploader
end

<% form_for @gallery %>
 <fields>

<%= f.fields_for :gallery_pictures do |builder| %>

<% end %>
<% end %>
```

controller should be same as it generate from scaffold